# Argument #2 ($componentData) must be of type array, null given, called in magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4

1. I am beginner in Magento.
2. I have faced an issue in magento 2.4.4 and i have no idea to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Check name of your ui component. maybe you set in layout something like product_listing and file products_listing.xml